# Docker externally-accessible registry, 502 Proxy Error, TLS handshake error

Tags: linux, docker, proxy, tls1.2, docker-registry

**Docker version:**

Client:
Version: 17.06.2-ce
API version: 1.30
Go version: go1.8.3
Git commit: cec0b72
Built: Tue Sep 5 19:57:21 2017
OS/Arch: linux/amd64

Server:
Version: 17.06.2-ce
API version: 1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
Go version: go1.8.3
Git commit: cec0b72
Built: Tue Sep 5 19:59:19 2017
OS/Arch: linux/amd64
Experimental: false

**docker exec 96f0cb141c8b registry --version:**
registry github.com/docker/distribution v2.6.2

**Reproducing my error:**

```
docker run -d --restart=always --name registry5000 -v `pwd`/certs:/certs -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:5000 -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/cert.pem -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KE
Y=/certs/privkey.pem -p 5000:5000 registry:2

docker push registry.domain.com/my-registry
```

output is:

*The push refers to a repository [registry.corobor.com/my-registry]
73c12ad782ae: Retrying in 1 second

98b882d4bdc0: Retrying in 1 second

f9cee97711b2: Retrying in 1 second

3de32dfabd85: Retrying in 1 second

2b0fb280b60d: Retrying in 1 second

received unexpected HTTP status: 502 Proxy Error*

**The log of my registry container:**
time="2017-09-15T10:04:43Z" level=warning msg="No HTTP secret provided - generated random secret. This may cause problems with uploads if multiple registries are behind a load-balancer. To provide a shared secret, fill in http.secret in the configuration file or set the REGISTRY_HTTP_SECRET environment variable." go.version=go1.7.6 instance.id=001581a2-0296-439e-b8c1-26edb84fc2b3 version=v2.6.2

2017/09/15 10:19:28 http: TLS handshake error from 10.10.10.202:44402: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake

2017/09/15 10:19:28 http: TLS handshake error from 10.10.10.202:44414: tls: oversized record received with length 21536

**My message:**
Hello,
I'm beginner on the subject. My company needs an externally-accessible registry in order to push in images which can be pull by client when they acces to *registry.domain.com*.
I followed the instructions from the docker official website to create this registry an I used LetsEnscrypt to get my pem certificate files. Here I use port 5000, but also use port 80 which gives the same error...
As written in "Reproducing my error", I had an 502 Proxy Error and TLS handshake error from my proxy. I've searched for many solutions in the forum but nothing convincing.

Do you please have any ideas how to fix it to make my registry available?

Thanks

Comment: You are running registry on 5000 and accessing it on port 80?

Comment: No, I only make it on the 80 now, the situation has changed, now my registry container is created then when I push an image I've got this output: `05d392f56700: Preparing
2b0fb280b60d: Preparing
denied: requested access to the resource is denied`        I well have the certificate for the website, do you have any idea about this reject?